# Пустой toolbox в VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

В VS15 перестали отображаться элементы в toolbox. Раньше можно было оттуда радиобаттоны тырить, а сейчас пишет:

> there are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this
>   text to add it to the toolbox.

Перепробовал всё, что нагуглил: перезапускал идю, делал ресет для тулбокса, делал choose items, show all, перезагружал комп, удалял кэши в appdata, даже полностью переставил студию (полдня грузил!!!) - ничего не помогло.

Что делать? Help!!!

Comment: наверно у тебя не тот тип проекта. Проверь что именно формы

Comment: Мда на с++ там какая то магия http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli-winforms/thread1224010.html

Comment: @ValeraKvip раньше это работало в обычном win32 приложении